# Google Maps api - Drawing Manager - change color of circle handles

Tags: google-maps, drawing

Couldn't find anything in the reference, thought maybe someone here will know. How do I change the color of the handles used for editing a shape drawn with Google Maps Drawing Manager?

See attached image for the handles i'm referring to.
Many thanks!
Uri[image: Google maps drawing manager handles]

Comment: related question: [Google Map Circle Change Edit Handle Icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876523/google-map-circle-change-edit-handle-icon) (but only involves circles)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style editable circle controls in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474683/how-to-style-editable-circle-controls-in-google-maps)

Comment: @Uri Klar if you got the idea how to change the _Handel Icon_ .I will be happy if you  update my fiddle. I also want to learn how to change. From http://jsfiddle.net/bmf5p500/2/ , I am unable to change the Handel icon in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/jj7e0094/) (Drawing Manager). And Add answer post.